# JavaScript JSON Array Numbers Are Inconsistent

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have the JSON which includes an array for each key.  Most of the time, when I access a number with a leading zero, it returns the number as an integer.  (This is what I expect.)

When I try to access the number 0400 through 0577 (inclusive) it returns a number that seems to be relative to 256.

Can anyone help me understand why this happens for this range of numbers?

```
var priceList = {
    "1":['Product 1',0400, 1375,0200],
    "2":['Product 2',0425, 0599,0200],
    "3":['Product 3',0399, 0579,0200] }

alert(priceList[1][1]);   // I expect it to alert 400 -- Actual Alert: 256
alert(priceList[2][1]);   // I expect it to alert 420 -- Actual alert: 277
alert(priceList[3][1]);   // I expect it to alert 399 -- Actual alert: 399
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think is better u convert it string first. refer below. that works for me

```
var priceList = {
"1":['Product 1','0400', 1375,0200],
"2":['Product 2','0425', 0599,0200],
"3":['Product 3','0399', 0579,0200] }
```

Answer (score 1):

In javascript, numbers with a leading zero are not considered to be correct, when used in the way you use them.
There are different types of numbers, for example binary ,decimal, octal and hexadecimal.

JavaScript thinks the leading zero indicates an octal integer, so it tries to convert those into octal base.

If you put:

```
"1":['Product 1',Number("0400"), 1375,0200]
```

It will output 400 as expected

Comment: Of course, that is no longer JSON. Maybe `"1":['Product 1', 400, 1375, 200]` would be better.

Comment: `'400'` is a string and not a number which changes the type of the data stored.

Comment: Well, he mimght have some use for the 0 in the beginning, so he might want to store as string and then convert to integer, if not 400 is the the best choice

Comment: True, but it looks like all the number are just being 0 padded to 4 digits. I am sure this 0 padding was just a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

That's not JSON. That's just a numeric literal within an array literal within an object literal in JavaScript. [JSON is a data interchange format](http://www.json.org/) that just happens to be based off of JavaScript's syntax.

JavaScript numeric literals can be:

- decimals i.e. `1234.5678`
- integers i.e. `123456789`
- scientific notation i.e. `1234e5678`
- hexadecimal i.e. `0xABC123`
- octal i.e. `0765`

So the issue you're seeing is that the numbers beginning with leading zeros are being parsed as octal.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you actually mean JSON and not just the JavaScript object literal syntax, what you have is not legal JSON since it contains a leading `0` in the number which is disallowed in JSON. For legal JSON, consider,

```
{ 
    "1": ["Product 1", 400, 1375, 200], 
    "2": ["Product 2", 425, 599, 200], 
    "3": ["Product 3", 399, 579, 200] 
}
```

Remember, JSON is a subset of the JavaScript object literal syntax.

If you really did mean the just the object literal syntax, and not JSON specifically, a leading `0` in a numeric literal is interpreted by JavaScript as an octal number, not a decimal number as you seem to expect. One of the reasons JSON forbids leading `0` is to ban octal encoding in JSON data to avoid just this type of confusion.